# How to use existing .db file in xCode4 for iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I have a phoneGap application and i am using existing .db file to use data. i used below given link http://gauravstomar.blogspot.ca/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+GauravSTomarBootstrappingIntelligence+(Gaurav+S+Tomar+:+Bootstrapping+Intelligence to use my db file in android app and it was successfully done. and now i am trying same thing in iOS, i used code given in above link to copy db file but i don`t know whether db file is copied at the proper location or not because when i fire select query i am getting error. plz help me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can check the copied database in the path `/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1`